# Secondary IP in its own netns namespace

Tags: linux, iproute2, network-namespace

Is there a way I can move a secondary IP into its own namespace while keeping the primary IP on the original device?

If I have 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 on device *eth0*, but I want 10.0.0.2 to be in its own netns `test`, the closest I've come to that involves adding a *veth* pair and a bridge, and moving the *eth0* primary IP to the bridge:

```
  netns: test              netns: default
==============     ===============================
vethB:10.0.0.2 <-> vethA <-> br0:10.0.0.1 <-> eth0
```

Unfortunately moving the 10.0.0.1 IP off of *eth0* will confuse a few opaque legacy applications on the box, so I'd prefer to keep that on *eth0*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Linux `macvlan`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=macvlan+linux) device is a workable solution here.

It instantiates a layer 2 subinterface which is a *bona fide* logical device, unlike the `eth0:1` administrative fiction to manage secondary IPs, which I may then move into a network namespace and address.  Example:

```
#  netns: test        netns: default
# ==============     ================
# test0:10.0.0.2 <->  eth0:10.0.0.1

# Create "test" network namespace
ip netns add test
ip netns exec test ip link set lo up

# Create subinterface and move to "test"
ip link add link eth0 name test0 type macvlan
ip link set test0 netns test

# Configure the subinterface
ip netns exec test ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 brd + dev test0
```

This preserves the "primary" IP on `eth0` and thus keeps the existing system more-or-less unaware of my hidden "secondary" IP.

**Addendum for wifi interfaces**

User [pts](https://serverfault.com/users/27885) points out that `macvlan` devices won't work if `eth0` is a *wifi* interface.  Instead, [use interface type `ipvlan mode 12`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622914/7703).

Comment: This doesn't work (e.g. `ping 10.0.0.2` from another machine on the local network) if a wifi interface is used instead of eth0. To make it work, replace `type macvlan` with `type ipvlan mode l2`. More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622914

Comment: To make it work with wiifi instead of Ethernet, replace *type macvlan* with *type ipvlan mode l2*. See details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622914/create-additional-ip-address-in-a-separate-network-namespace/622934

Answer (score 1):

A given device can only be in one namespace, see https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/ :

> Aside from the loopback device, each network device (physical or virtual interfaces, bridges, etc.) can only be present in a single network namespace.

So your `eth0` can only be in one. Your setup, with two virtual interfaces and a bridge is a solution to this problem. I do not understand what it changes for applications if the IP is tied to `br0` instead of `eth0`, they should not see a difference. Otherwise you will need to provide more details. Did you really get problems, and if so, which ones, or do you just expect them?

If you can uses them, have a look at VLANs: you can put each of them (off the same physical interface) in different namespaces. This is detailed here: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2014/03/21/a-follow-up-on-linux-network-namespaces/

If you can not use a bridge or VLANs, you will need to setup some IP forwarding or NAT.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on the L3 forwarding or NAT'ing?  802.1q VLANs are infeasible as I don't control the wire/trunking, and my veth-pair-bridge approach, again, would be too intrusive.  (I'm not pleased with that constraint, but so it is.)

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393468/211833  Basically the default route of vethB should be pointing to eth0 IP.